# How to find unused Amazon EC2 security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm try to find a way to determine orphan security groups so I can clean up and get rid of them. Does anyone know of a way to discover unused security groups.

Either through the console or with the command line tools will work (Running command line tools on Linux and OSX machines).

Comment: to clean up unused sg's, goto ec2 sg's console, select all security groups and action delete, so it will show the sg's which are not in use and delete only those sg's.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Note: this only considers security use in EC2, not other services like RDS.  You'll need to do more work to include security groups used outside EC2.   The good thing is you can't easily (might not even be possible) to delete active security groups if you miss one associated w/another service.

Using the newer AWS CLI tool, I found an easy way to get what I need:

First, get a list of all security groups

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[*].GroupId'  --output text | tr '\t' '\n'
```

Then get all security groups tied to an instance, then piped to `sort` then `uniq`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].SecurityGroups[*].GroupId' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | sort | uniq
```

Then put it together and compare the 2 lists and see what's not being used from the master list:

```
comm -23  <(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[*].GroupId'  --output text | tr '\t' '\n'| sort) <(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].SecurityGroups[*].GroupId' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | sort | uniq)
```

Comment: @Erik Yes, I only have a single region and the AWS scripts have their home region set via environmental variables.   I'd be interested in seeing a multi-region version of this script.

Comment: you may want to add a --filter for your vpc so you dont have to see other default vpc sg

Comment: To clarify the Note posted above, for example, if a VPC security group is assigned to an RDS instance that's in a VPC it will be counted as an unused security group. Be careful with that.

Comment: A security group may also be in use by an ELB.  This command will list the uniq set of security group IDs referenced by ELBs in the default region: `aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].SecurityGroups[*]' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | sort | uniq`

Comment: Should add --no-paginate to the above.

Comment: An EC2 security group may also be in use by an RDS instance.  This command will list the security group ID's used by RDS instances in the default region: `aws rds describe-db-security-groups --query 'DBSecurityGroups[*].EC2SecurityGroups[*].EC2SecurityGroupId' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | sort | uniq`

Comment: You can also use `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --query 'NetworkInterfaces[*].Groups[*].GroupId' --output text| tr '\t' '\n' | sort | uniq` to just describe the network interfaces.

Comment: @Jonathan 's point about describing network interfaces is important if you're running a Lambda in a VPC. In that case, Lambda will allocate an ENI that won't show up in any of the other lists given here. Of course these are short-lived, and if the Lambda is low-traffic, there might not be one there when you look, possibly leading to a false positive in your "unused SG" list. (i.e. it's unused at this moment, but it's still needed for future Lambda invocations).

Comment: Nice answer. Query tip: put the final element in brackets and you get one value per line when using text output, eliminating the need for the `tr` command. E.g., `--query 'SecurityGroups[].[GroupId]'` vs '--query 'SecurityGroups[].GroupId'`

Comment: I  could not test it, but this command should list the security group ID's used by Lambda Functions in the default region: `aws lambda list-functions --query 'Functions[*].VpcConfig[*].SecurityGroupIds[*]' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 73):

If you select all of your security groups in the EC2 console, then press actions -> Delete Security Groups, a popup will appear telling you that you cannot delete security groups that are attached to instances, other security groups, or network interfaces, and it will list the security groups that you can delete; ie the unused security groups.

NOTE: according to @andrewlorien’s comment this does not work for all types of AWS services.

Comment: While I must agree, using "select all + delete" is usually not really a good habit.

Comment: If you are uncertain if it will work you can just make a dummy security group and attach to it something, try deleting it, and see that it won't let you.

Comment: You don't need to actually confirm the delete, in the popup it will show you a breakdown of which ones can be deleted (orphan) and which can't. You can then press cancel and then delete the orphan ones.

Comment: What I don't get is this: If the AWS console can offer this information when you do this scary.maneuver, why don't they share how to do the same thing via the API?  Its not like this isn't something that is likely needed in brown field environments...

Comment: be brave :: do it

Comment: I haven't convinced myself yet that this "just try to delete the security groups" approach will work if the SG is associated with a Lambda that isn't _actively_ running.  Like, if you have a cron'd lambda that runs 1 minute every hour and you try to delete the security group in one of the other 59 minutes in that hour, does it work?  If it does work, then the Lambda should crap out the next time it wakes up, right?

Comment: @ThomasVaughan have you tested it with a dummy lambda?

Comment: Also : not all AWS services offer these types of warnings.  I won't tell you which ones, but if you assume that you'll get a warning every time you click delete, one day you'll take a production site offline (like i did last month)

Answer (score 34):

This is the sample code written in boto (Python SDK for AWS) to list the Security Group against number of instances it is associated with.

You may use this logic to obtain the same in command line as well

**Boto Code**

```
import boto
ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
sgs = ec2.get_all_security_groups()
for sg in sgs:
    print sg.name, len(sg.instances())
```

**Output**

```
Security-Group-1 0
Security-Group-2 1
Security-Group-3 0
Security-Group-4 3
```

Comment: well, yes, but what abou elbs?

Comment: Also note that this includes running instances only. You can't delete a SG which is linked to a stopped instance either.

Comment: This ignores interfaces from services like RDS. RDS owns the instance, but you own the ENI. I think ElasticSearch and ELB work similarly and wouldn't show up with this script

Comment: What if the security group is used by any ecs service?

Answer (score 9):

Among other functions, both [ScoutSuite](https://github.com/nccgroup/ScoutSuite) and [Prowler](https://github.com/toniblyx/prowler) report unused EC2 Security Groups. Both are open source.

Comment: Both seem very difficult to use. Prowler produced a list of 162 security groups in various regions for me but it said only 6 in a single region are used which is not correct. I couldn't get ScoutSuite to run a single rule because the docs say to clone an existing Ruleset but doesn't say where to find one.

Answer (score 8):

After about a year of unaudited use, I found it necessary to audit my AWS EC2 security groups and clean up legacy, unused groups.

This was a daunting task to perform via the web GUI, so I looked to the AWS CLI to make the task easier.  I found a start on how to do this at StackOverflow, but it was far from complete.  So I decided to write my own script.  I used the AWS CLI, MySQL and some “Bash-foo” to perform the following:

1. Get a list of all EC2 security groups.
   I store the group-id, group-name and description in a tabled called “groups” in a MySQL database called aws_security_groups on the localhost.  The total number of groups found is reported to the user.
2. Get a list of all security groups associated with each of the following services and exclude them from the table:
   EC2 Istances
   EC2 Elastic Load Balancers
   AWS RDS Instances
   AWS OpsWorks (shouldn’t be removed per Amazon)
   Default security groups (Can’t be deleted)
   ElastiCache

For each service I report a count of the number of groups left in the table after the exclusion is complete.

3. Finally I display the group-id, group-name and description for the groups that are left.  These are the “unused” groups that need to be audited and/or deleted.  I’ve found that SG’s between instances and Elastic Load Balancers (ELBs) often refer to each other.  It’s best practice to do some manual investigation to ensure they are truly not in use prior to removing the cross references and deleting the security groups.  But my script at least pares this down to something mor manageable.

NOTES:
1.  You will want to create a file to store your MySQL host, username and password and point the $DBCONFIG variable to it.  It should be structured like this:

```
[mysql]
host=your-mysql-server-host.com
user=your-mysql-user
password=your-mysql-user-password
```

2. You can change the name of the database if you wish – make sure to change the $DB variable in the script

Let me know if you find this useful or have any comments,fixes or enhancements.

Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Initialize Variables
DBCONFIG="--defaults-file=mysql-defaults.cnf"
DB="aws_security_groups"
SGLOOP=0
EC2LOOP=0
ELBLOOP=0
RDSLOOP=0
DEFAULTLOOP=0
OPSLOOP=0
CACHELOOP=0
DEL_GROUP=""

# Function to report back # of rows
function Rows {
    ROWS=`echo "select count(*) from groups" | mysql $DBCONFIG --skip-column-names $DB`
#   echo -e "Excluding $1 Security Groups.\nGroups Left to audit: "$ROWS
    echo -e $ROWS" groups left after Excluding $1 Security Groups."
}


# Empty the table
echo -e "delete from groups where groupid is not null" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB

# Get all Security Groups
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[*].[GroupId,GroupName,Description]" --output text > /tmp/security_group_audit.txt
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a myArray
do
    if [ $SGLOOP -eq 0 ];
    then
        VALUES="(\""${myArray[0]}"\",\""${myArray[1]}"\",\""${myArray[2]}"\")"
    else
        VALUES=$VALUES",(\""${myArray[0]}"\",\""${myArray[1]}"\",\""${myArray[2]}"\")"
    fi
    let SGLOOP="$SGLOOP + 1"
done < /tmp/security_group_audit.txt
echo -e "insert into groups (groupid, groupname, description) values $VALUES" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB
echo -e $SGLOOP" security groups total."


# Exclude Security Groups assigned to Instances
for groupId in `aws ec2 describe-instances --output json | jq -r ".Reservations[].Instances[].SecurityGroups[].GroupId" | sort | uniq`
do
    if [ $EC2LOOP -eq 0 ];
    then
        DEL_GROUP="'$groupId'"
    else
        DEL_GROUP=$DEL_GROUP",'$groupId'"
    fi
    let EC2LOOP="$EC2LOOP + 1"
done
echo -e "delete from groups where groupid in ($DEL_GROUP)" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB
Rows "EC2 Instance"
DEL_GROUP=""


# Exclude groups assigned to Elastic Load Balancers
for elbGroupId in `aws elb describe-load-balancers --output json | jq -c -r ".LoadBalancerDescriptions[].SecurityGroups" | tr -d "\"[]\"" | sort | uniq`
do
    if [ $ELBLOOP -eq 0 ];
    then
        DEL_GROUP="'$elbGroupId'"
    else
        DEL_GROUP=$DEL_GROUP",'$elbGroupId'"
    fi
    let ELBLOOP="$ELBLOOP + 1"
done
    echo -e "delete from groups where groupid in ($DEL_GROUP)" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB
Rows "Elastic Load Balancer"
DEL_GROUP=""


# Exclude groups assigned to RDS
for RdsGroupId in `aws rds describe-db-instances --output json | jq -c -r ".DBInstances[].VpcSecurityGroups[].VpcSecurityGroupId" | sort | uniq`
do
    if [ $RDSLOOP -eq 0 ];
    then
        DEL_GROUP="'$RdsGroupId'"
    else
        DEL_GROUP=$DEL_GROUP",'$RdsGroupId'"
    fi
    let RDSLOOP="$RDSLOOP + 1"
done
    echo -e "delete from groups where groupid in ($DEL_GROUP)" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB
Rows "RDS Instances"
DEL_GROUP=""

# Exclude groups assigned to OpsWorks
for OpsGroupId in `echo -e "select groupid from groups where groupname like \"AWS-OpsWorks%\"" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB`
do
    if [ $OPSLOOP -eq 0 ];
    then
        DEL_GROUP="'$OpsGroupId'"
    else
        DEL_GROUP=$DEL_GROUP",'$OpsGroupId'"
    fi
    let OPSLOOP="$OPSLOOP + 1"
done
echo -e "delete from groups where groupid in ($DEL_GROUP)" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB
Rows "OpsWorks"
DEL_GROUP=""

# Exclude default groups (can't be deleted)
for DefaultGroupId in `echo -e "select groupid from groups where groupname like \"default%\"" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB`
do
    if [ $DEFAULTLOOP -eq 0 ];
    then
        DEL_GROUP="'$DefaultGroupId'"
    else
        DEL_GROUP=$DEL_GROUP",'$DefaultGroupId'"
    fi
    let DEFAULTLOOP="$DEFAULTLOOP + 1"
done
echo -e "delete from groups where groupid in ($DEL_GROUP)" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB
Rows "Default"
DEL_GROUP=""

# Exclude Elasticache groups
for CacheGroupId in `aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --output json | jq -r ".CacheClusters[].SecurityGroups[].SecurityGroupId" | sort | uniq`
do
    if [ $CACHELOOP -eq 0 ];
    then
        DEL_GROUP="'$CacheGroupId'"
    else
        DEL_GROUP=$DEL_GROUP",'$CacheGroupId'"
    fi
    let CACHELOOP="$CACHELOOP + 1"
done
echo -e "delete from groups where groupid in ($DEL_GROUP)" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB
Rows "ElastiCache"

# Display Security Groups left to audit / delete
echo "select * from groups order by groupid" | mysql $DBCONFIG $DB | sed 's/groupid\t/groupid\t\t/'
```

And here is the sql to create the database.

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host:  localhost   Database: aws_security_groups
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.40-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `groups`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `groups`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `groupid` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `groups`
--

LOCK TABLES `groups` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `groups` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `groups` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2015-01-27 16:07:44
```

Answer (score 3):

A boto example printing the Group IDs and Names *only* of the security groups that have no current instances.

It also shows how to specify which region you are concerned with.

```
import boto
import boto.ec2
EC2_REGION='ap-southeast-2'
ec2region = boto.ec2.get_region(EC2_REGION)
ec2 = boto.connect_ec2(region=ec2region)
sgs = ec2.get_all_security_groups()
for sg in sgs:
    if len(sg.instances()) == 0:
        print ("{0}\t{1}".format(sg.id, sg.name))
```

To confirm which security groups *are* still being used you should reverse or remove the `if len(sg.instances()) == 0` test and print the `len(sg.instances())` value out.

E.g.

```
print ("{0}\t{1}\t{2} instances".format(sg.id, sg.name, len(sg.instances())))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the node.js AWS SDK I can confirm that AWS doesn't allow you to delete security groups that are in use.  I wrote a script that simply tries to delete all groups and gracefully handles the errors.  This works for classic and the modern VPC.  The error message can be seen below.

```
Err { [DependencyViolation: resource sg-12345678 has a dependent object]
  message: 'resource sg-12345678 has a dependent object',
  code: 'DependencyViolation',
  time: Mon Dec 07 2015 12:12:43 GMT-0500 (EST),
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 30 }
```

Answer (score 2):

To the SGs attached to the network interfaces:

By name:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --output text --query NetworkInterfaces[*].Groups[*].GroupName | tr -d '\r' | tr "\t" "\n" | sort | uniq
```

By id:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --output text --query NetworkInterfaces[*].Groups[*].GroupId | tr -d '\r' | tr "\t" "\n" | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the same info.
How to find all security groups that are not attached to any resource? And I found this:
Using AWS config rule "EC2_SECURITY_GROUP_ATTACHED_TO_ENI," I got a list of checks that non-default security groups are attached to Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instances or elastic network interfaces (ENIs). The rule returns NON_COMPLIANT if the security group is not associated with an EC2 instance or an ENI.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the chosen answer is not as accurate as I need (I've tried to investigate the why, but I've preferred to implement it).
If I check ALL `NetworkInterfaces`, looking for attachments to any `SecurityGroup`, It gets me partial results. If I check only on `EC2Instances`, it gets me back partial results as well.

So that's my approach to the problem:

1. I get ALL EC2 SecurityGroups -> `all_secgrp`
2. I get ALL EC2 Instances -> `all_instances`
3. For each Instance, I get all SecurityGroups attached to it

   1. I remove from all_secgrp each of these SecurityGroup (because attached)
4. For each SecurityGroup, I check an association with any NetworkInterfaces (using the `filter` function and filtering using that `security-group-id`)

   1. IF no association is found, I remove the security-group from `all_secgrp`

Attached you can see a snippet of code. Don't complain for efficiency, but try to optimize it if you want.

```
all_secgrp = list(ec2_connector.security_groups.all())
all_instances = ec2_connector.instances.all()

for single_instance in all_instances:
    instance_secgrp = ec2_connector.Instance(single_instance.id).security_groups
    for single_sec_grp in instance_secgrp:
        if ec2.SecurityGroup(id=single_sec_grp['GroupId']) in all_secgrp:
            all_secgrp.remove(ec2.SecurityGroup(id=single_sec_grp['GroupId']))

all_secgrp_detached_tmp = all_secgrp[:]
for single_secgrp in all_secgrp_detached_tmp:
    try:
        print(single_secgrp.id)
        if len(list(ec2_connector.network_interfaces.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'group-id', 'Values': [single_secgrp.id]}]))) > 0:
            all_secgrp.remove(single_secgrp)
    except Exception:
        all_secgrp.remove(single_secgrp)

return all_secgrp_detached
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question and I'm sure there are more ways to skin this AWS cat, but here's my solution in bash (you'll need `jq` for this to work):

```
REGION="eu-west-1"

SGLIST=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[*].GroupId' | jq -r .[])

echo $SGLIST | xargs -n1 | while read SG; do  [ "$(aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=group-id,Values=$SG --region $REGION | jq .NetworkInterfaces)" != '[]' ] || echo $SG; done
```

Remember to replace REGION with whatever region you're using.
The 1st step is to get a list of security groups.
Then we're checking for each security group if there's a network interface associated with it - this is not limited to EC2 instances, it checks anything that has a network interface (LBs, RDS, etc).
For reference see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-find-security-group-resources/).

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool in the AWS marketplace that makes this a lot easier. It shows you which groups are attached/detached for easy deletion, but it also compares your VPC Flow Logs against the security group rules and shows you which SG rules are in use or unused. AWS posted an ELK-stack solution to do this, but it was ridiculously complex.

Here's the tool, and a disclaimer that I worked on it. But I hope you all find it pertinent:
https://www.piasoftware.net/single-post/2018/04/24/VIDEO-Watch-as-we-clean-up-EC2-security-groups-in-just-a-few-minutes

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem, if you have security groups that reference other security groups in the rules. If so, you'll have to resolve DependencyErrors, which is not trivial.

If you are only using IP addresses, then this solution will work, after you create a boto3 client:

```
# pull all security groups from all vpcs in the given profile and region and save as a set
all_sgs = {sg['GroupId'] for sg in client.describe_security_groups()['SecurityGroups']}

# create a new set for all of the security groups that are currently in use
in_use = set()

# cycle through the ENIs and add all found security groups to the in_use set
for eni in client.describe_network_interfaces()['NetworkInterfaces']:
    for group in eni['Groups']:
        in_use.add(group['GroupId'])

unused_security_groups = all_sgs - in_use

for security_group in unused_security_groups:
    try:
        response = client.delete_security_group(GroupId=security_group)
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DependencyViolation':
            print('EC2/Security Group Dependencies Exist')
    else:
        print('Unexpected error: {}'.format(e))
```

Comment: This won't cover SGs used by RDS

Answer (score 0):

The general command to list unused security groups is:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?attachmentCount==`0`]"
```

But this will list only the security groups for the current region. If you want to find unused SG in all regions you can run a windows script batch like the one below:

```
@echo off
REM Get all available regions
for /f "tokens=*" %%R in ('aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[].RegionName" --output text') do (
    set regions=%%R
)
echo Regions: %regions%
for %%R in (%regions%) do (
    echo Running command for region: %%R
    call aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region %%R --query "SecurityGroups[?attachmentCount==`0`]"
)
```